# I need to prove $x^{2}+ y^{2}= 1$ is a closed set in $R^{2}$ using the complementary set proof with sphere $B(a, r)$ with interior points

Tags: calculus, general-topology

$x^{2}+ y^{2}= 1$ is a closed set with complimentary set open sphere proof in $R^{2}.$

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: Before your question gets downvoted (possibly to oblivion), please consider providing some of your own work.

Comment: I have tried to define set A as x^2+y^2=1 with A^c as x^2+y^2 != 1. Then trying to find how I can prove A^c is open I tried creating points *a* which give: B(a,r) st A^c is open but I'm stuck on that part, really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)$ be a point not in the set. Let $r=x^2+y^2 \neq 1$. Try to show that the ball around $(x,y)$ of radius $r-1$ (if $r>1$) or $1-r$ (if $r < 1$) shows the point to be an interior point of the complement.